# Installing Jellyfin via Ubuntu's bionic repository

Tags: applications, repositories

The Jellyfin media app has instructions to [install it via repository](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/administration/installing.html#ubuntu-repository) for Ubuntu releases (supported releases are xenial, bionic, cosmic, disco, eoan, and focal).

The issue is with step 4. (shown below) because the command `lsb_release -c -s` returns `hera`, and this is not a Ubuntu release.

Will it work if I manually set `bionic`, which is the Ubuntu release that elementary OS is based on? Or will I bork my system?

---

Installation instructions:

> 1. Install HTTPS transport for APT if you haven't already:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install apt-transport-https
>    ```
> 2. Enable the Universe repository to obtain all the FFMpeg dependencies:
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository universe
>    ```
> 3. Import the GPG signing key (signed by the Jellyfin Team):
>
>    ```
>    wget -O - https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu/jellyfin_team.gpg.key |
>    sudo apt-key add -
>    ```
> 4. Add a repository configuration at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jellyfin.list`:
>
>    ```
>    echo "deb [arch=$( dpkg --print-architecture )]
>    https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu $( lsb_release -c -s ) main" | sudo
>    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jellyfin.list
>    ```
> 5. Update APT repositories:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    ```
> 6. Install Jellyfin:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install jellyfin
>    ```
> 7. Manage the Jellyfin system service with your tool of choice:
>
>    ```
>    sudo service jellyfin status
>    sudo systemctl restart jellyfin
>    sudo /etc/init.d/jellyfin stop
>    ```

Comment: Change manually to bionic for a while and then go back to hera.

Comment: I'm sorry, change what manually? And then go back what to hera?

Comment: Ech. You wrote this. Will it work if I manually set bionic, which is the Ubuntu release that elementary OS is based on? Or will I bork my system? I answered. I thought you will understand my answer.

Comment: You mean I should add the `https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu bionic main` repository, update the repositories, install Jellyfin, and then remove this repository?

Comment: I mean to change the name in /etc/os-release for a while from hera to bionic. You can add the repository as you mentioned and you do not have to remove it. But if you will not change the release name I am afraid it will not install, because it will be looking for the proper release name. The second way is to change the source code for Jellyfin but I doubt it is a good idea, however I am sure the developer should add it for Elementary OS in the future, but I doubt it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way is to edit simple **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jellyfin.list** and add the specific ubuntu-version name 'bionic or focal" according the version of Elementary is running.
Then the sources update allow to find jellyfin package like a charm.

`deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu bionic main`

OR

`deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu focal main`

PS: Elementary latest versions according to Ubuntu versions like:

- 5.1 (Hera) ==========> Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)
- 6.0 (Odin) ==========> Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)
- 6.1 (Jolnir) ==========> Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)